# ASP.NET Membership - Change password WITH asking the old

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

If I'm not first who asks this question sorry for duplication. I know how to change password WITHOUT asking old. But how to do it with asking old password?

Regards Alexey

Comment: If you know that you are not only one that asks this, why don't you use answers of others instead of asking again?

Comment: I said "if I'm not first", not "I know I am not first". Be more attentive.

Comment: do you just want to redesign ASP.NET standard password recovery control to ask for old password?

Comment: As a variant. If you know how to redesign ASP.NET standard password recovery control to ask for old password, please said. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Membership controls into a template that is defined in the markup as a table that contains ASP.NET controls such as Label and TextBox . You can then use these elements or add your own to create a custom template for your Login control. Notice that the same control IDs are used for the controls that make up the Login template as in the default template.
To use a template with the membership controls

1.Place a control on a page in Design view.

2.Right-click the control and select Convert to Template from the shortcut menu.

Do it and try to add some custom logic to membership provider, you can derive membership provider, and configure to use your one

Hope this helps